# Error importing scikit-learn modules

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm trying to call a function from the cluster module, like so:

```
import sklearn
db = sklearn.cluster.DBSCAN()
```

and I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'cluster'
```

Tab-completing in IPython, I seem to have access to the base, clone, externals, re, setup_module, sys, and warning modules.  Nothing else, though others (including cluster) are in the sklearn directory.

Following pbu's advice below and using

```
from sklearn import cluster
```

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 2, in <module>
    from sklearn import cluster
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cluster\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .spectral import spectral_clustering, SpectralClustering
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cluster\spectral.py", line 13, in <module>
    from ..utils import check_random_state, as_float_array
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .class_weight import compute_class_weight, compute_sample_weight
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\class_weight.py", line 7, in <module>
    from ..utils.fixes import in1d
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\fixes.py", line 318, in <module>
    from scipy.sparse.linalg import lsqr as sparse_lsqr
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\__init__.py", line 109, in <module>
    from .isolve import *
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\isolve\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .iterative import *
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\isolve\iterative.py", line 7, in <module>
    from . import _iterative
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I'm using Python 3.4 on Windows, scikit-learn 0.16.1.

Comment: I don't understand, how do you import `sklearn`?

Comment: why dont you resinstall? may be sklearn is corrupt.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem was with scipy/numpy install.  I'd been using the (normally excellent!) unofficial installers from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/.  Uninstall/re-install from there made no difference, but installing with the official installers (linked from http://www.scipy.org/install.html) did the trick.

Comment: Numpy worked for me from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ but scipy was awkward and had to download the win32 superpack.exe from sourceforge. All working now though. Thanks Jon.

Answer (score 31):

You probably don't use Numpy+MKL, but only Numpy.

I had the same problem and reinstalling Numpy with MKL

`pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall "numpy‑1.16.3+mkl‑cp37‑cp37m‑win32.whl"`

fixed it.

Note: update the file to the latest version, possibly 64bit - see [the list of available Windows binaries](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy)

Comment: If you're running on 64-bit you can install Numpy + NKL from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy

Answer (score 2):

I am using `anaconda` got the same error as the OP, when loading Orange, or PlotNine.
I can't recall when this start to happen.

Tracing the dependency of `Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\scipy\special\_ufuncs.cp36-win32.pyd`, `libifcoremd.dll` and `libmmd.dll` are missing in DependencyWalk. Searching them in anaconda root directry, they are located in both ICC_RT and one version of MKL package.

<s>Adding `Anaconda3\pkgs\mkl-2017.0.3-0\Library\bin` to PATH, seems to fix SciPy and NumPy related DLL load failure, the above package starts to work again.</s>

I still don't know how to fix this properly. Apparently the downside is that the MKL package could be updated and versions may change so does the path. In this aspect Its equally inconvenient as adding a non-managed package.

Reinstalling ICC_RT fixed the issue for me, `libmmd.dll` and the related dlls are automatically copied into `anaconda3/library/bin` afterwards, which is automatically added into `PATH` by `activate` command. All previous numpy/scipy related `cant load DLL` errors are gone now.

Answer (score 2):

From the error log, it shows that **scipy module** is the most recent module fails to import

```
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\fixes.py", line 318, in <module>
    from scipy.sparse.linalg import lsqr as sparse_lsqr
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\__init__.py", line 109, in <module>
    from .isolve import *
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\isolve\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .iterative import *
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\isolve\iterative.py", line 7, in <module>
    from . import _iterative
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I have the same error that show the same log, the problem'd gone when I uninstall/install scipy:

```
pip uninstall scipy
pip install scipy
```

Answer (score 0):

Place this line on top of the python file

```
from sklearn import cluster
```

That should do it :))

Comment: this generates a different error; see update to original post.

Answer (score 0):

For me what fixed it were these commands:

```
pip uninstall sklearn
pip uninstall scikit-learn
pip uninstall scipy
pip install scipy
pip install scikit-learnhere
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and solved it by installing/updating the **mkl** package:

```
conda install mkl
```

or

```
pip install mkl
```

Just for full information, this also downgraded the following packages:

The following packages will be UPDATED:

```
mkl:          2017.0.4-h6d528fc_0 defaults --> 2018.0.3-1         defaults
```

The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:

```
numpy:        1.11.3-py34_0       defaults --> 1.10.1-py34_0      defaults
pandas:       0.19.2-np111py34_1  defaults --> 0.18.1-np110py34_0 defaults
scikit-learn: 0.18.1-np111py34_1  defaults --> 0.17-np110py34_1   defaults
scipy:        0.19.1-np111py34_0  defaults --> 0.16.0-np110py34_0 defaults
```

Answer (score 0):

I struggled trying to figure this one out; tried to download and install the (unofficial) Numpy+MKL library from the website (risky/tedious?).

Ultimately found success by:

1. Login to command prompt using admin rights; how to here: https://superuser.com/questions/968214/open-cmd-as-admin-with-windowsr-shortcut
2. Uninstall existing/tangled version of Scipy & Numpy

   `pip uninstall scipy
   pip uninstall numpy`
3. Fresh install Scipy & Numpy

   `pip install scipy
   pip install numpy`
4. Run Jupyter notebook; it worked for me.

The message ***ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found***
informs that there is failure to identify and source the required DLL(s) to use the scikit-learn library; a fresh install of scipy/numpy probably enables a better routing of DLL connections called from Jupyter notebook code(s).

Answer (score 0):

download microsoft visual c++ distribution

link : https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=53840

vc_redist.x64.exe

install and run this .exe file in your computer.. the DLL import module error will not appear after this

now it will work fine enjoy :)

Comment: This issue was reported 4 years ago while the issue with visual C++ is due to some openmp packaging and only valid for scikit-learn 0.22