# Import Errors with Python script run in R

Tags: python, r, numpy, rstudio

I have a Python program, which searches for an anomaly (First train, then test). Now I need to start this Python program from RStudio. I have read about `system('python myfirstpythonfile.py')`, but when I launch my Python program in this way I have import errors with `numpy`, `scipy`, etc.

How can I launch my Python program from RStudio?

Comment: By "problems with `numpy`" do you mean it can't import it?

Comment: Please specify what those *problems* are. As a test, run same line in your command line interpreter - Bash/PowerShell and see the output.

Comment: @Parfi can you post the error messages you get (e.g. if you get an `ImportError` as suspected)? Then your question can be re-opened.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Having problems importing `numpy` or `scipy` suggests that your script is not running in the correct Python *environment*. It is possible to install multiple versions of Python on a computer, and which one is run when you type `python` is determined by the `PATH` setting. It may be that when RStudio executes your script (via `python myfirstpythonfile.py`) it is launching the wrong Python — a version of Python on your computer that does not have the `numpy` packages installed.

You can test if this is the case by running the following on the command line and seeing what it outputs:

```
python -c "import sys; print(sys.executable)"
```

You can try the same from within RStudio:

```
system('python -c "import sys; print(sys.executable)"')
```

If it gives a different result, you can pass the result of the first as an absolute path to python (changing /path/to/python for the correct value for your system):

```
system('/path/to/python myfirstpythonfile.py')
```

As you mention in the comments that you are actually trying to use Python3, then you may be able to simply do the following from within RStudio:

```
system('python3 myfirstpythonfile.py')
```

This will run your script using your installed Python3 and the associated packages/libraries.

Comment: @Parfi did you try running the above commands and checking the output?

Comment: Maybe you are right.
- python -c "import sys; print(sys.executable)" - gave me Python 2.7
- system('python -c "import sys; print(sys.executable)"') - gave me Python 2.7 but I use Python 3.5 (there I have all the libraries)

But if I try system('Path/.../Programs/Python/Python35-32/ myfirstpythonfile.py'), I get warning massage with status 127

Comment: Ah use `python3 -c "import sys; print(sys.executable)"` to get the full path to your `python3`

Comment: @Parfi see the edit: you may be able to just call `python3` from inside RStudio

Comment: I had seen. Thank you, now 1. program work correct, but 2. program has new problem. Exactly this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34588339/import-scipy-sparse-failed
And this problem don't like me, because I will have to install Python 3.4 and all libraries, etc. :-)

Comment: @Parfi If this solution worked for you can accept the answer (the tick mark). I'll take a look at the other question