# Syntax for importing scipy and sklearn modules

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, scipy, python-import

I use (just the standards) Win10, Anaconda-2018.12, Python-3.7, MKL-2019.1, mkl-service-1.1.2, Jupyter ipython-7.2. [see here e.g.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30766274/error-importing-scikit-learn-modules)
I"m wondering why the following syntax works for `import` statements with the `numpy` modules but does not work for `scipy` or `sklearn` modules:

```
import scipy as sp
import numpy as np
A = np.random.random_sample((3, 3)) + np.identity(3)
b = np.random.rand((3))
x = sp.sparse.linalg.bicgstab(A,b)

> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call
> last) <ipython-input-1-35204bb7c2bd> in <module>()
>       3 A = np.random.random_sample((3, 3)) + np.identity(3)
>       4 b = np.random.rand((3))
> ----> 5 x = sp.sparse.linalg.bicgstab(A,b)
> AttributeError: module 'scipy' has no attribute 'sparse'
```

or with sklearn

```
import sklearn as sk
iris = sk.datasets.load_iris()

> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call
> last) <ipython-input-2-f62557c44a49> in <module>()
>       2 import sklearn as sk
> ----> 3 iris = sk.datasets.load_iris() AttributeError: module 'sklearn' has no attribute 'datasets
```

**This syntax however does work** (but are for rare commands not really lean):

```
import sklearn.datasets as datasets
iris = datasets.load_iris()
```

and

```
from scipy.sparse.linalg import bicgstab as bicgstab
x = bicgstab(A,b)
x[0]
```

> `array([ 0.44420803, -0.0877137 ,  0.54352507])`

What type of problem is that ? Could it be eliminated with reasonable effort ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## The "problem"

The behavior you're running into is actually a feature of Scipy, though it may seem like a bug at first glance. Some of the subpackages of `scipy` are quite large and have many members. Thus, in order to avoid lag when running `import scipy` (as well as to save on usage of system memory), `scipy` is structured so that most subpackages are not automatically imported. You can read all about it in [the docs right here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/api.html).

## The fix

You can work around the apparent problem by exercising the standard Python `import` syntax/semantics a bit:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.random.random_sample((3, 3)) + np.identity(3)
b = np.random.rand((3))

import scipy as sp

# this won't work, raises AttributeError
# x = sp.sparse.linalg.bicgstab(A,b)

import scipy.sparse.linalg

# now that same line will work
x = sp.sparse.linalg.bicgstab(A,b)
print(x)
# output: (array([ 0.28173264,  0.13826848, -0.13044883]), 0)
```

Basically, if a call to `sp.pkg_x.func_y` is raising an `AttributeError`, then you can fix it by adding a line before it like:

```
import scipy.pkg_x
```

Of course, this assumes that `scipy.pkg_x` is a valid `scipy` subpackage to begin with.

Comment: thank you ! I was not aware of  "scipy is structured so that most subpackages are not automatically imported". It helps to understand what's on !