# Python package dependency is causing an error

Tags: python, dll, filepath, python-packaging

The folder `Python37\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\isolve\` inside Scipy package in Python has the following file: `_iterative.cp37-win_amd64.pyd`.

When I run a Python file, I get the following error :- 
`File "C:\......\Python37\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\isolve\iterative.py", line 10, in <module>
    from . import _iterative
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found`

(I am new to Python on Windows)

Comment: Are you using conda?

Comment: No, not using conda

Comment: Sounds like your installation is corrupted. See also here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30766274/error-importing-scikit-learn-modules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I was able to resolve the issue (on Windows) :- 
1. I uninstalled Python using python.exe program. 
2. Installed anaconda for Windows - it installs python along with dependencies and many common libraries.

Answer (score 0):

As I cannot comment due to a lack of reputation:

Have you installed scypy with all the mentioned dependencies on their website?

```
python -m pip install --user numpy scipy matplotlib ipython jupyter pandas sympy nose
```

(Taken from https://www.scipy.org/install.html)

Comment: Did not solve the problem, thanks for the suggestion though!