# Import error when importing scipy to Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy, selenium-chromedriver

"pip install scipy" did not work for me, so I installed it from here: [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy)

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.interpolate as si
```

When I try to import scipy, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "path to my file :)", line 4, in <module>
    import scipy.interpolate as si
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\scipy\__init__.py", line 153, in <module>        
    from scipy._lib._ccallback import LowLevelCallable
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\scipy\_lib\_ccallback.py", line 1, in <module>   
    from . import _ccallback_c
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _ccallback_c: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: possibly helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/30869318/1248974

Comment: I tried everything, nothing seems to work :(

Comment: Which minor version of Python 3.10 do you have installed? The error is likely related to the Pre-release Python version not yet being supported by scipy

Comment: I fixed it by removing all the Python versions on my pc and installing the newest one. After that "pip install scipy" worked.